# Mysql search between two date with time

Tags: php, mysql

how to search between two date , when date format in database like :

```
2015-10-10 02:23:41 am
```

i just want to search between two date with format :

```
2015-10-10
```

without

```
02:23:41 am
```

any ideas please ?

Comment: define *"not working"*

Comment: What format has fiel date?

Comment: What is the  `02` at the end of your date: `'2015-09-10 02'`

Comment: seriously doubting OP's going to respond to any of these comments and expecting a magical answer to appear below. Not going to happen; not with me anyway.

Comment: With respect, sometimes it's hard to know how to ask the right question.

Comment: I think we also need to motivate the junior programmers as well otherwise critise is very easy..... just my opinion... thinking of senior programmers always big than to juniors... well HAPPY NEW YEAR ALL

Comment: do you mean they are stored as a string (CHAR/VARCHAR)?

Comment: thank you guys i think i have not asking right question , by way or other that thing what i want to asking about 
how can i do query for search between two date if column type is ( varchar ) and date format like : 2015-10-10 02:23:41 am
so if i have 5 records in database , 2015-10-10 02:23:41 am , 2015-10-10 02:23:41 am , 2015-10-10 02:23:41 am ,2015-10-10 02:23:41 am ,2015-10-10 02:23:41 am and i want to search with this format 2015-10-10 how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't completely clear. But, I guess you hope to find all the rows in your table where `Date` occurs on or after midnight on `2015-08-05` and before midnight on `2015-09-11` (the day after the end of the range you gave in your question.

Those two search criteria will find all the rows with `Date` values in the range you specified.  (I'm ignoring the `02` at the end of `2015-09-10 02` in your question because I can't guess what it means, if anything.)

Try this query:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM table
   WHERE `Date` >= '2015-08-05'
     AND `Date` <  '2015-09-10' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

This has the benefit that it can exploit an index on the `Date` column if you have one, so it can be fast.

You could write

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM table            /* slow! */
   WHERE DATE(`Date`) BETWEEN '2015-08-05' AND '2015-09-10'
```

That's slightly easier to read, but the WHERE condition isn't [*sargable*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable), so the query will be slower.

Notice that the beginning of the range uses `>=` -- on or after midnight, and the end of the range uses `<` -- before midnight.

Pro tip: Avoid the use of reserved words like `DATE` for column names. If you make mistakes writing your queries, their presence can really confuse MySQL, not to mention you, and slow you down.

Comment: DATE is not a reserved word

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest:

```
select * from table where cast(date as date) between '2015-08-05' and '2015-09-10'
```

When your where clause is based on a timestamp, but you're using date as the parameters for your between, it excludes anything that happens on the second date unless it happened precisely at midnight.

Answer (score 0):

When using the end date for the range, include the time of the end of the day:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-08-05' AND '2015-09-10 23:59:59'
```